# Haskell function definition and arguments list

Tags: function, haskell

I have the following function definitions (which are equivalent):

```
reverseWords :: String -> String
reverseWords wds = unwords . map reverse . words $ wds
```

and

```
reverseWords :: String -> String
reverseWords = unwords . map reverse . words
```

I understand that they are equivalent as they yield the same result but I'm a bit confused about the second form.

If I call a function like:

```
reverseWords abc
```

How does haskell decide where to place this 'abc' parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell does not need to decide where to place `abc`. When you call `reverseWords` in your second example it will simply return `unwords . map reverse . words`.

And then abc gets applied to that with which you will end up with the same result as in your first example.

This is also called Point-free style as you can read more about it here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Point-free

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!